# Graph Partitioning Algorithm Implemented in R

Tags: r, graph-theory

Do any R packages include an implementation of a graph partition algorithm such as the [Kernighhan-Lin Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernighan%E2%80%93Lin_algorithm)?

Comment: I don't know, but a good starting point for these sorts of questions is CRAN's [Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/), which contains one for graphical models.

Comment: ...or a search on http://www.rseek.org

Answer (score 1):

There is the CRAN package [RBGL](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RBGL) which wraps the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) -- but you would have to check first whether this latter library contains that partitioning algorithms.

Comment: The package is now in [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/3.3/bioc/html/RBGL.html). Nonetheless, there's no partitioning algorithm in current version, although Boost contains e.g. [Stoer-Wagner](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/stoer_wagner_min_cut.html) algorithm.